# Silverlight Dockpanel Border Style

Tags: silverlight

Does anyone know how to add a border to a Dockpanel. i have this:

```
<Style x:Key="DockPanelStyle" TargetType="controlsToolkit:DockPanel">        
    <Setter Property="Border">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>
```

However it sends an error that Property border is not correct

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="4" Width="200" Height="150">
  <controlsToolkit:DockPanel ... />
</Border>
```

Comment: I want to do it in my ResourceDictionary as the Dockpanel is programatically created.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. But of course you can create Border object in code and apply style to it - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.border(v=VS.95).aspx.